# PHP creates mysql table, but also gives out "Table not created" error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following script to create tables in a mysql database

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$con = "mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, '')";
$create=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$table_name` (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,high TEXT ,low TEXT ,Divergence TEXT ,Change_Percent TEXT ,Low_Price TEXT ,High_Price TEXT ,Low_Proximity TEXT ,Vol_Index TEXT ,Vol TEXT ,Purchase_Value TEXT)");

                    if (mysql_query($con,$create))
                        {
                        echo "Table created successfully";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        echo "Error creating table: " . mysql_error($conn);
                        }
```

Executing the script does create an the desired table, however it also gives the following error

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 136
Error creating table:
```

Now according to me this means $create returns "FALSE" which would be the case if the table was not created, however in this case the table has been created, what then is making it a Boolean? and How can I stop this error??

Comment: `$con = "mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, '')";` is assigning `$con` the string `mysql_connect(…)`.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes that is delibrate, as initially I used to get an error saying `mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given` that is when I made it a string instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks one and all the problem is finally solved, as stated in most answers I ran the create command twice once in `$create` and once in `if(mysql_query($con,$create))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the condition should be

```
                    if ($create)
                    {
                    echo "Table created successfully";
                    }
```

u have already run the query 
and u are pasing again the `mysql_query($con,$create)`

Answer (score 1):

You are running the `$create` query twice. try this:

```
 if ($create)
 {
    echo "Table created successfully";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You supply second parameter for `mysql_query()` which causes an error. Also, you misspelled `$con` in `mysql_error()`. Use this code instead:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, ''); // error: string instead of function
$create=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$table_name` (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,high TEXT ,low TEXT ,Divergence TEXT ,Change_Percent TEXT ,Low_Price TEXT ,High_Price TEXT ,Low_Proximity TEXT ,Vol_Index TEXT ,Vol TEXT ,Purchase_Value TEXT)");

                    if ($create) // error: second mysql_query()
                        {
                        echo "Table created successfully";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        echo "Error creating table: " . mysql_error($con); // error: misspelled con
                        }
```

Comment: You're not supplying the second parameter to `mysql_query`.  In that case, PHP will use `mysql.default_host` instead of `$dbhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is not a connection, it's a string:

```
$con = "mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, '')";
```

Try creating a real connection instead:

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, '');
```

You are also running `mysql_query` twice. The first is without a connection parameter.  Try running it once instead.  And the connection should be the second, not the first, parameter:

```
$create = "CREATE TABLE ...";
if (mysql_query($create, $con)) {
```

Comment: When I make $create a string I get an error saying `expects parameter to be resource, string given` the same goes with $con giving an error saying `expects parameter to be string, resource given`